# What is the difference between $Increment and $Sequence functions?

Tags: intersystems-iris

What is the difference between $Increment and $Sequence functions and when to use one over the other?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is - $Sequence is faster in cases when you have massive parallel inserts into the database.
Here is a [good article](https://community.intersystems.com/post/sequence-function) on $Sequenece and $Increment differences